# Excel VBA: Populating Staggered Ranges with 2d Array data

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I'm currently looking for a more efficient method, via VBA, to get information transferred from a 2-d array within a Sub into a staggered set of ranges within an excel workbook.  I've distilled what I need into an example below, complete with code; any help will be greatly appreciated.

I've linked images describing an example of what I'm working with (Input, Array, and Output), and written an example of the code that I'm using below.  For the sake of simplicity let's define "Input Sheet" as Sheet1 and "Output Sheet" as Sheet2 within the workbook:

[image: Input Sheet]

```
  Option Explicit

  Sub TransferData()
    Dim myArray as Variant           'Define the array to hold the data.
    Dim i as integer                 'Define a generic loop counter variable.

    myArray = Sheet1.Range("A1:F7")  'Pulls all the relevant data into the array.
```

myArray now looks exactly like the range. (I'd post 3rd link, but I need to earn some more rep first).

I want to transfer the data into my output file so that it looks like this:
[image: Output Sheet]

Here is how I currently approach the situation:

```
    For i = 1 to ubound(myArray)
      Sheet2.Cells(i,1) = myArray(i,1)
      Sheet2.Cells(i,3) = myArray(i,2)
      Sheet2.Cells(i,6) = myArray(i,3)
      Sheet2.Cells(i,7) = myArray(i,4)
      Sheet2.Cells(i,8) = myArray(i,5)
      Sheet2.Cells(i,9) = myArray(i,6)
    Next i
  End Sub
```

My question is this; is there a way to transfer the data from the array to the staggered ranges in a way similar to how I grabbed the array; a range at a time?  For example, something along the lines of:

```
Sheet2.Range("A1:A8") = myArray(1 to 7, 1)  'Note: this is total pseudocode
Sheet2.Range("C1:C8") = myArray(1 to 7, 2)  'Note: this is total pseudocode
```

etc... etc...

I believe I've managed to teach myself a fair amount of VBA so far, but I definitely don't know everything, and this is something i need help with.  I'm trying to minimize the amount of writes to the worksheets from VBA; they really take their toll.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I assume there's a reason you're not just using `=Sheet1!B1` as the formula for cell C2 of Sheet2, etc.

Comment: Also, it's not an answer per se, but turning off the screen painting will probably speed up your existing algorithm tremendously (`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`).  Just don't forget to turn it back on in your error handler and before you exit your routine.

Comment: Absolutely.  first off, thank you for adding in the images in!  The users who are going to be editing sheet1 have a habit of deleting rows, and I'm trying to avoid any #REF errors that might pop up if they delete a referenced cell.  My workaround was to simply flash the entire range into an array and handle things through a quick read/write.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks again; I definitely turn off screenupdating, but what really gets me in the real-world application is the fact that I'm dealing with a 2d array that's, at max, 500 rows x 96 columns, and that makes the cell-by-cell writing loop really tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Copying and pasting" the values might be quite a bit faster.  You'll obviously need to generalize this to fit your purposes, but this code works with the sample you provided:

```
Sub TransferData()

    Sheet3.Range("A1:A7") = Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Value
    Sheet3.Range("C1:C7") = Sheet1.Range("B1:B7").Value
    Sheet3.Range("F1:I7") = Sheet1.Range("C1:F7").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: This answer actually made me facepalm, because I was so focused on the array that I forgot about simply using this method.  You, sir, set me on a track to reduce the run time of a macro by several orders of magnitude.  Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the "other data" to insert, one very simple way of approaching this is to transfer all of your data into the output range, then insert new columns and place the other data as appropriate.

For example:

```
data = Worksheets("InputSheet").Range("A1:F7").Value
Worksheets("OutputSheet").Range("A1:F7").Value = data
Worksheets("OutputSheet").Columns("B").EntireColumn.Insert ' do this for every column you need, within reason.
```

You could then drop your "other data" into all of the new columns you had created.

Comment: Thanks Paul; I appreciate the input (pun intended).  I've taken what you and mwolfe said and put it to good use, and I appreciate the help!